# How to add a vertical dividerline?

Tags: output-formatting, list-manipulation

I am preparing some sheets with Boolean expression identies using TableForm's like the following:

```
TableForm[
 Reverse[Boole[BooleanTable[
    {a, b, Implies[a, b], Or[Not[a], b], Implies[Not[b], Not[a]]},
    {a, b}]]],
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"P", "Q", "P => Q", "\[Not]P \[Or] Q", 
    "\[Not]Q => \[Not]P"}}
 ]
```

The output of the function above is however not entirely what I want. Ideally I would
like to see a vertical divider line to the right of the second ("Q") column.

How can I add this vertical dividerline?

Perhaps I ask too much of Tableform, so I went to Grid:

```
Grid[
 Reverse[Boole[BooleanTable[
    {a, b, Implies[a, b], Or[Not[a], b], Implies[Not[b], Not[a]]},
    {a, b}]]]
 ]
```

But that puts me back to figuring out how to add columnheaders, and a nice
horizontal dividerline.

( updated 09:31 )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Ideally I would like to see a vertical divider line to the right of
> the second ("Q") column.

Instead of

```
TableForm[
 Reverse[Boole[BooleanTable[
    {a, b, Or[And[Not[a], b], b]},
    {a, b}]]],
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"P", "Q", "\[Not]P \[And] Q \[Or] Q"}}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can do

```
data = Reverse[
  Boole[BooleanTable[{a, b, Or[And[Not[a], b], b]}, {a, b}]]]
header = {"P", "Q", "\[Not]P \[And] Q \[Or] Q"};
Grid[Prepend[data, header], 
 Dividers -> {{False, False, True}, {False, True}}, 
 Spacings -> {1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And if you want the alignment left as with table

```
Grid[Prepend[data, header], 
 Dividers -> {{False, False, True}, {False, True}}, 
 Spacings -> {1, 1}, Alignment -> Left]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And if you want to change the style of the vertical lines, you can change `FrameStyle`

```
Grid[Prepend[data, header], 
 Dividers -> {{False, False, True}, {False, True}}, 
 Spacings -> {1, 1}, Alignment -> Left, FrameStyle -> Gray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I find `Grid` and `Dividers` easier to work with than `TableForm`

**Updated for the updated question:**

You can do the same thing. Instead of

```
TableForm[
 Reverse[Boole[
   BooleanTable[{a, b, Implies[a, b], Or[Not[a], b], 
     Implies[Not[b], Not[a]]}, {a, b}]]], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"P", "Q", "P => Q", "\[Not]P \[Or] Q", 
    "\[Not]Q => \[Not]P"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can use Grid

```
data = Reverse[
  Boole[BooleanTable[{a, b, Implies[a, b], Or[Not[a], b], 
     Implies[Not[b], Not[a]]}, {a, b}]]]
header = {"P", "Q", "P => Q", "\[Not]P \[Or] Q", "\[Not]Q => \[Not]P"};
Grid[Prepend[data, header], 
 Dividers -> {{False, False, True}, {False, True}}, 
 Spacings -> {1, 1/2}, Alignment -> Left, FrameStyle -> Gray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: What happened to the 4th and 5th column, I wonder ? ( My bad, I'll update the question. )- So this is not possible with TableForm? I suppose it must be Grid then, thank you.

Comment: @niloderoock what 4th and 5th column? Your table only has 3 columns?  You might be able to add the vertical line with TableForm. I do not know. I use Grid myself.

Comment: Sorry! I updated the Q. The grid though has 5 columns.

Comment: @niloderoock  fyi, updated,

Comment: So, in essence it is all about the Dividers. ;-)

Comment: @niloderoock Yes. That is what I meant. Combination  of `Grid` + `Dividers` gives you what `TableForm` does but easier to adjust and play around.

Comment: Thank you very much, answer accepted.